# Hiding data structure for sqlite file stored on Dropbox, using password protection

Tags: ios, security, sqlite, core-data, password-protection

I have been searching this thread to find the best way to hide the *data structure* for a Sqlite file used by Core Data in an iOS app. I have found many questions that address the desire to keep data from the end user, but I am primarily interested in protecting my data structure (and secondarily, to keep the user from messing with his data). I am currently using Dropbox to back up my app's Sqlite file, and as it stands, anyone can open the file and see the data structure. In my new app, I would still like to use Dropbox, as it has worked well so far; but I do not want the end user to be able to open the database file. I just want the app to be able to upload or download the file.

It seems as though encryption of the entire file may be overkill, and I do not want to encrypt individual fields because I am more interested in the structure. I have seen a couple of posts that have asked about password protection/encryption, but usually the answers address encryption, and I have not been able to find much on password protection.

From what I have learned (and please correct me if I am wrong): 
1) CommonCrypto would be best for field level encryption and is probably not what I am looking for.
2) OpenSSL and SQLCipher will encrypt the database, but may slow performance (and may be overkill for me)

Is there a simple way to provide password protection for the SQLite file, and still be able to read/write with Core Data? I realize that I would have to store the password within the app, which would make it fairly easy for a hacker, but I am okay with this. I am just looking to provide one extra level of protection for myself (as far as the data structure) and for the end user (so that they can't muck with/mess up their data).

Comment: Are you just concerned with the backup file that goes into Dropbox? If that's the case, why not just zip archive and protect it with a password?

Comment: @Rog, I'm not sure how to do that. Is there an api for that in iOS?

Comment: ZIPArchive is what I currently use. Lightweight, simple and effective, with password protection support for zip files too. http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

Comment: @Rog This looks great - I think it will work for me. Thanks! If you post this as an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only concerned with the Sqlite file that you are backing up to Dropbox, you can using something lightweight like ZipArchive to zip and password protect your file before saving it.

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

Cheers,

Rog

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I know storing the password in the app is not the best idea, but since I have to store it there, do you have any suggestions for the best place to store it? I was thinking just as plain text in a view controller, but if you have a better suggestion I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Maybe store a base64 encoded version of it and use a method to decode it when you need to zip/unzip. There should be some good examples of objective c base64 encoding decoding on Google. might be overdoing it though ;)